# Make dynamic query with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I am trying to make a dynamic condition using Mongoose but it doesn't work as I imagined.

the code is like this

```
id = req.params.questionId;
index = req.params.index;

callback = function(err,value){
   if(err){

       res.send(err)

   }else{

       res.send(value)

    }
};

conditions = {
    "_id": id,
    "array._id": filterId
};
updates = {
   $push: {
      "array.$.array2."+index+".answeredBy": userId
   }
};
options = {
  upsert: true
};

Model.update(conditions, updates, options, callback);
```

As you see, I am trying to make dynamic condition using "index" variable. Is it possible to do like this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create your `updates` object in two steps:

```
var updates = { $push: {} };
updates.$push["array.$.array2." + index + ".answeredBy"] = userId;
```

**Update**

Now that node.js 4+ supports [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), you can do this in one step:

```
var updates = { $push: {
    ["array.$.array2." + index + ".answeredBy"]: userId
} };
```

Comment: Or with Object.create